# GreenDAO onUpdate

Tags: android, greendao

When I update the database version it's not dropping all the tables (thought I'll be the default behaviour). Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: You mean you change the schema? If you want to change the DB schema. You should change the schema version in Generator and re-generate the code again. Or you want to do some db migration when you upgrade your DB so you want to customize the onUpgrade part?

Answer (score 2):

Which SQLiteOpenHelper are you using?

Check your generated DaoMaster class. It has an inner class DevOpenHelper which drops all tables on update.

Answer (score 2):

Please check DaoMaster.java

```
@Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.i("greenDAO", "Upgrading schema from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " by dropping all tables");
            dropAllTables(db, true);
            onCreate(db);
        }
```

Make Sure  dropAllTables(db, true); have true and again problem exist debug here